# Meaning of 'intellectual vertigo'

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I'd never come across the phrase 'intellectual vertigo' until reading an [article in The Economist](https://www.economist.com/interactive/science-and-technology/2023/04/22/large-creative-ai-models-will-transform-how-we-live-and-work) about AI. The sentence goes,

> By working in the most human of mediums, conversation, ChatGPT is now allowing the internet­-using public to experience something similar, a kind of **intellectual vertigo** caused by software which has improved suddenly to the point where it can perform tasks that had been exclusively in the domain of human intelligence.

What does it mean?

Comment: What do you think it means?

Comment: The text says that the sudden progress of artificial intelligence cannot fail to make one dizzy.

Comment: Not everything has already been written. *This is not a set phrase*; it is just creative journalistic writing. The Economist has the best writing of its kind of any news publication in the English-speaking world.

Comment: @Graffito This makes sense now.

Comment: *Intellectual vertigo* reminds me of an earlier, related term *information sickness*. First used by the late Ted Mooney in his debut novel *Easy Travel to Other Planets*, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ted_Mooney

Comment: It's a metaphor. What it means is up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not every combination of words is a compound noun recognised by all English speakers. 'Intellectual vertigo' isn't a real thing, just like 'brain fuel' isn't a real thing, but from knowing what the individual words mean you would understand it must be something that fuels the brain. So what could 'intellectual vertigo' mean?

Literal vertigo is a physical feeling of unbalance or dizziness. It is not necessarily caused by heights, yet so many people associate the word with the uneasiness that comes from a fear of heights that it is often accepted as a synonym (the classic movie *Vertigo* features a protagonist with a fear of heights).

*Intellectual Vertigo* has been coined by the writer to suggest a similar fear or feeling of unease over their experience with AI. The stimulation for this feeling is intellectual, rather than physical. They may even have chosen this because of the association with heights - perhaps suggesting that the fear comes from feeling that AI has metaphorically risen too 'high' to either challenge or surpass human intellect.

Comment: And by putting it in all caps, it now sounds like a title...

Comment: @barmar No, this doesn't fit the definition of a metaphor. A metaphor is when you use a term out of context, for example "*the law **is** an ass*". The kind of speech the OP is referring to is more like the ad hoc creation of a new compound noun to denote something specific. For example, '*virtual queue*' is not a metaphor, even though it isn't a *literal* queue - it's a new name for something specific and it is a little bit *like* queuing (and saying something is 'like' something else is a simile, not a metaphor, but it isn't that either).

Comment: The original and default definition of 'vertigo' refers to a physical experience, dizziness. Just how much physical distress is caused by the program is debatable, but if there is none in some cases, the usage is metaphorical. cf 'This situation is causing the Government headaches' for 'This situation is causing the Government real problems'. Dictionaries nowadays often list metaphorical broadenings as distinct senses, but a dead metaphor is still a metaphor.